# WordPress Capabilities: edit_user vs edit_users

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-roles, security, capabilities

The [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_users) only mentions `edit_users`, but in the source I found many places are using `edit_user`, what is the difference?

Are there any conventions for singular and plural capabilities? e.g. `edit_post` vs `edit_posts`?

Comment: In which source -- plugins, themes, WordPress core?

Comment: One such occurrence is here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php#L249

Answer (score 1):

I found a few references to `edit_user` as a capability, one of which is this:

> ```
> // Allow user to edit itself
>     if ( 'edit_user' == $cap && isset( $args[0] ) && $user_id == $args[0] )
>     break;
> ```
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1005

I believe the comment in that block of code answers this question.

Per @PatJ, it looks like [`map_meta_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap) converts (in a sense) `edit_user` into `edit_users` but only if the user attempting to edit the profile is the profile's owner, thus allowing users who otherwise have no user edit capabilities to edit their own profile information.

Comment: If I'm reading the code right (and there's no guarantee of that), the `map_meta_cap()` function maps `edit_user` to `edit_users`.

Comment: @PatJ : I believe you are correct, but only if the user attempting to edit the profile is the same as the user profile.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.